# Where can I find openCL sdk for graphic card HD4400

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencl, intel

I looked at intel web site and it sems that they replaced opencl aapplication development SDK with a new software that only support new HD graphic cards (5th generation).

My laptop has HD4400, where can I find Intel SDK for it?

I know that I can use any SDK, but I believe Intel one is pretty good for Opencl, as NVIDA is trying to force everybody to use CUDA which I am not interested to do.

I am developing on windows using visual studio 2013 and I like the Intel integrated tools for VS for opencl development.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Starter Edition of OpenCL Code Builder from Intel, which should include the SDK. To be able to run you programs on the iGPU, you need to install the driver/runtime from https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers.